# how to get stock status in opencart product page

Tags: php, opencart

I want to show

> out of stock

on my product page and I change the status from admin and is updated in admin but on my product page there is also same

> In Stock

and product page code is

```
        if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
                $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['stock_status'];
            } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
                $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
            } else{
                $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');

        }
```

and language page is

```
$_['text_outstock']     = 'Out of Stock';
```

Now what condition is used there?

Comment: Were exacly is the problem? `echo $this->data['stock'];`?

Comment: on controller/product.php  $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');

Comment: Your question is completely unclear, 
If you want to show out of stock message, 
Just set the product qty to 0, and in setting>option> out of stock to out of stock

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your issue, you can set it directly in the Admin to show 'out of stock' message.

You need to set it both in the general settings AND in the invidividual product.

Currently, because you did not set your Admin settings correctly, `$product_info['stock_status']` does not display 'out of stock'.

However, if you insist of modifying the code, you need to use the following:

```
 if ($product_info['quantity'] <= 0) {
      //out of stock message
      $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_outstock');
  } elseif ($this->config->get('config_stock_display')) {
      //in stock, and displaying exact quantity
      $this->data['stock'] = $product_info['quantity'];
  } else{
      //in stock, but just display a message not exact quantity
      $this->data['stock'] = $this->language->get('text_instock');
  }
```

Hope this helps!